# Jquery Function Errors - Tic Tac Toe

Tags: jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- Assignment 11 : jQuery I -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=600"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
    <div id="players">
        <div id="X" class="">Player X</div>
        <div id="O" class="">Player O</div>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="New Game" id="newGame"/>
    </div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="c0"></td>
            <td id="c1"></td>
            <td id="c2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c3"></td>
            <td id="c4"></td>
            <td id="c5"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="c6"></td>
            <td id="c7"></td>
            <td id="c8"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on this assignment for my Javascript / Jquery Class. We are editing the `getBoard` and `squareClicked` function to find a win within the game.

The `checkWin` function was preprogrammed for us, so the error should not be there.

I'm having trouble reading the `squareclicked` function and changing the background colors of the squares that won the game. It could be my `getBoard` function coded wrong as well.

Any help would be amazing.

This assignment focuses on Jquery, so keep in mind I must use that for the two functions listed above.

/*
    WEB 230
    Starting file for Assignment 11 (Lab 19 Solution)
    {Megan Caza}
*/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#X').addClass('current-player');

    function switchPlayer() {
        var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
        $('#players div').removeClass('current-player');
        if(player === 'X') {
            $('#O').addClass('current-player');
        } else {
            $('#X').addClass('current-player');
        }
    }

    $('table').on('click', squareClicked);

    function squareClicked(e) {
        var $sqr = $(e.target);
        var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
        if(!$sqr.attr('class')) {
            $sqr.addClass(player + '-marker');
            switchPlayer();
        }
        checkWin();
        if(win == true) {
            $('winArray').css('background-color','#33CC99');
            alert('Player ' + winner + ' won!');
        }
    }

    $('#newGame').on('click',newGame);

    function newGame() {
        $('td').removeAttr('class');
        $('#O').removeClass('current-player');
        $('#X').addClass('current-player');
    }

    // Get an array of markers on each square
    function getBoard() {
        var board = [];
        // Step 1: Your code here
             $('td').each(function() {
                    var className = $(this).attr('class');
                    if (className == null) {

                    }

                    else {
                        board[this] = className.substring(0,1);
                        //alert(className.substring(0,1));   
                    }
            }); 

        return board;
    }

    // This function is provided. You don't need to change it.
    // Check for winner
    function checkWin() {
        var board = getBoard();
        // array of possible win sets
        var winArray = [
            [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8],
            [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8],
            [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ];
            var winInfo = {win: false};
        // loop through the possible win sets
        for(var i=0; i<winArray.length; i++) {
            // get the marks at the three win locations
            a = board[winArray[i][0]];
            b = board[winArray[i][1]];
            c = board[winArray[i][2]];
            // see if the same marker is at each location
            if(a && a === b && b === c) {
                winInfo.win = true;
                winInfo.play = winArray[i];
                winInfo.winner = a;
                return winInfo;
            }
        }
        return winInfo;
    }

});
```

Comment: can you add html codes?

Comment: The html is on a separate file, so we can only edit what is on the javascript file.

Comment: selectors might be an issue aswell that is why I want to see the html code :) it may also help other people here

Comment: Added HTML. Hope that helps :D

Comment: Code Snippets are useless if you don't construct them to function.  Removed.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm having trouble reading the squareclicked function and changing the background colors of the squares that won the game.

Ok, first of all, you need a game board. Try adding some CSS, so that you can see the grid.

CSS:

```
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Next, you want to track each square that was clicked on & not the table itself. So change this:

```
$('table').on('click', squareClicked);
```

Into this:

```
$('td').on('click', squareClicked);
```

Generally we use `<div>` tags instead of `<table>` or `<tr>` or `<td>` tags, since CSS likes to fight with `<table>`, `<tr>` & `<td>` tags. But for now, we can use tables... since your still learning about programming.

When I press F12, I see this error in the console.log:

> (index):68 Uncaught ReferenceError: win is not defined

So what we do is add "object detection", which checks to make sure that the "win" object isn't set to undefined or null.

Change:

```
if(win == true) {
```

To this long-hand version:

```
if ((typeof(win) !== 'undefined') && (win === true)) {
```

Or this short-hand version, because win will only be true if it's not undefined & not null:

```
if (win && (win === true)) {
```

Ok, let's see what other problems that exist in this code....

First of all, the variable "win" must be defined somewhere using either:

`var win = ... something ...;` or `let win = ... something ...;`

So you have to define what it's supposed to be doing, inside of this function:

```
function squareClicked(e) {
```

Fork this JSfiddle & experiment with it for awhile, to see what you can make it do: https://jsfiddle.net/briankueck/028qpabe/

I won't do your homework for you... as that would take away your struggle, which is needed to become a better programmer. However, I don't mind pointing you in the right direction, to become a better programmer.

Good luck with the code & let me know what you discover from fiddling with it! I'm pretty much here every day & can help you out in a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I believe on @Clomp, take this homework as a challenge for you.
But anyway I just like to point out what could be wrong in the code that might help you.

`var className = $(this).attr('class');`

> This returns undefined since table elements e.g., not all td have a class by the time that getBoard() invoked.

`$('winArray').css('background-color','#33CC99');`

> $('winArray') is not a valid selector there is no $('winArray') in the html codes and i also dont think that **winArray** is a valid tag.

`alert('Player ' + a + ' won!');`

> object a is not defined.

`if(checkWin())`

> checkWin returns an object, you could use checkWin().win to return a boolean value. or better declare new variable.

```
a = board[winArray[i][0]];
b = board[winArray[i][1]];
c = board[winArray[i][2]];
```

> create a variable before adding a value on them.

`winInfo.play and winInfo.winner`

> both of them are also undefined. and I don't think you need winInfo.play you can just remove it.

Please try to understand things first, before checking the demo I created for you. As this might affect your future to become a better programmer :)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#X').addClass('current-player');

 function switchPlayer() {
  var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
  $('#players div').removeClass('current-player');
  if(player === 'X') {
   $('#O').addClass('current-player');
  } else {
   $('#X').addClass('current-player');
  }
 }

 $('table').on('click', squareClicked);
 
 function squareClicked(e) {
  var $sqr = $(e.target);
  var player = $('.current-player').attr('id');
  if(!$sqr.attr('class')) {
   $sqr.addClass(player + '-marker');
   switchPlayer();
  }
    var winInfo = checkWin();
    if(winInfo.win) {
      alert('Player ' + winInfo.winner + ' won!');
    }
 }
 
 $('#newGame').on('click',newGame);
 
 function newGame() {
  $('td').removeAttr('class');
  $('#O').removeClass('current-player');
  $('#X').addClass('current-player');
 }
 
 // Get an array of markers on each square
 function getBoard() {
  var board = [];
  // Step 1: Your code here
            $('td').each(function(index, element) {
             var className = '';
              if ($(element).attr('class')){
               className = $(element).attr('class');
                board.push(className.substring(0,1));
              }
              else board.push(className);
     });
  return board;
 }
 
 // This function is provided. You don't need to change it.
 // Check for winner
 function checkWin() {
  var board = getBoard();
    // array of possible win sets
  var winArray = [
   [0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8],
   [0,3,6], [1,4,7], [2,5,8],
   [0,4,8], [2,4,6] ];
      
    var winInfo = {
      win: false,
      winner: ''
    };
    
  // loop through the possible win sets
    var a, b, c;
    for(var i=0; i<winArray.length; i++) {
      // get the marks at the three win locations
      a = board[winArray[i][0]];
      b = board[winArray[i][1]];
      c = board[winArray[i][2]];
      // see if the same marker is at each location
      if((a && a === b) && b === c) {
        winInfo.win = true;
        winInfo.winner = a;
        return winInfo;
      }
    }
  return winInfo;
 }
 
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.X-marker {
  background-color: blue;
}

.O-marker {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
 <div id="players">
  <div id="X" class="">Player X</div>
  <div id="O" class="">Player O</div>
  <input type="button" class="button" value="New Game" id="newGame"/>
 </div>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td id="c0"></td>
   <td id="c1"></td>
   <td id="c2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="c3"></td>
   <td id="c4"></td>
   <td id="c5"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td id="c6"></td>
   <td id="c7"></td>
   <td id="c8"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```